# Is it possible to symbolically solve minimisation problem for N-dimensional vector?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geometry, vector

I'm interested in the problem of finding the points that represents the distance between 2 lines in N-dimensional space (N >= 3).

Assuming that line 1 has 2 points $A_1$ and $X_1$, and line 2 has 2 points $A_2$ and $X_2$, each of which is represented by a N-dimensional vector, the problem can be defined as minimising the following expression:

$$\left\| t_1 \left(A_1-X_1\right)+X_1-t_2 \left(A_2-X_2\right)-X_2\right\| {}^2$$

```
In[25]:= f=Norm[(Subscript[t, 1](Subscript[A, 1] - Subscript[X, 1]) + Subscript[X, 1] - Subscript[t, 2](Subscript[A, 2] - Subscript[X, 2]) - Subscript[X, 2])]^2
Out[25]= Norm[Subscript[t, 1] (Subscript[A, 1]-Subscript[X, 1])+Subscript[X, 1]-Subscript[t, 2] (Subscript[A, 2]-Subscript[X, 2])-Subscript[X, 2]]^2
```

But Mathematica seems to be unable to solve it:

```
In[26]:= ArgMin[f, {Subscript[t, 1], Subscript[t, 2]}]
Out[26]= ArgMin[Norm[Subscript[t, 1] (Subscript[A, 1]-Subscript[X, 1])+Subscript[X, 1]-Subscript[t, 2] (Subscript[A, 2]-Subscript[X, 2])-Subscript[X, 2]]^2,{Subscript[t, 1],Subscript[t, 2]}]
```

Is it beyond Mathematica's capability? Or I made a mistake in defining the problem?

**UPDATE** I later explicitly defined all $A_*$ and $X_*$ as 3D vectors:

```
In[24]:= $Assumptions=(Subscript[A, 1]|Subscript[A, 2]|Subscript[X, 1]|Subscript[X, 2])\[Element]Vectors[3,Reals]
Out[24]= (Subscript[A, 1]|Subscript[A, 2]|Subscript[X, 1]|Subscript[X, 2])\[Element]Vectors[3,Reals]
```

But it doesn't solve the problem: The result is still the same :-<

Comment: I think you will find that Mathematica has little or no support for "abstract" N-vectors, abstract matricies, abstract sums, etc. Choose a specific concrete N (actually probably choose n because N is already defined as the name of an internal Mathematica function) and concrete points and you will instantly get an answer

Comment: I actually confined them to 3D vectors, but with no luck

Comment: You're still using abstract vectors. You need to put in explicit coordinates: `nm = Norm[p ({x2, y2, z2} - {x1, y1, z1}) + {x1, y1, z1} - q ({x4, y4, z4} - {x3, y3, z3}) - {x3, y3, z3}]^2 /. Abs -> Identity; Solve[Thread[D[nm, {{p, q}}] == 0], {p, q}] // Simplify`. The full symbolic result is a bit gnarly tho.

Comment: It is indeed very gnarly and totally not generalisable when D > 14, is there a better way for vector/matrix/tensor symbolic deduction? Not necessarily using Mathematica.

Comment: Perhaps this http://sections.maa.org/lams/proceedings/spring2001/bard.himel.pdf or this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152688/what-is-the-shortest-distance-between-skew-lines-in-n-dimensions will get you where you need to go. If not then a Google search for "n dimensions minimum distance between skew lines", without the quotes, which is where I found both of those, looks promising.

Comment: @Bill, of course they can do it manually :) But that's not the purpose of using symbolic computing

Comment: Sometimes looking at how someone else was able to simply solve a problem can show you how you might let Mathematica know what you want done in a way that it might succeed. Until computers implement the "just do what I mean" button then either this or having gained expertise in guessing how to present a problem to Mathematica or asking the net to show you how to do it seems like your alternatives to possibly actually getting a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one possibility, using [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) instead of [`Norm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm):

```
dsquared = #.#&[t1(A1-X1)+X1-t2(A2-X2)-X2]
```

> (t1 (A1 - X1) + X1 - t2 (A2 - X2) - X2).(t1 (A1 - X1) + X1 - t2 (A2 - X2) - 
>      X2)

Now, use [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand) with appropriate assumptions:

```
expand = TensorExpand[
    dsquared,
    Assumptions->Element[t1|t2, Arrays[{}]] && Element[A1|A2|X1|X2, Vectors[{d}]]
]
```

> t1^2 A1.A1 - 2 t1 t2 A1.A2 + 2 t1 A1.X1 - 2 t1^2 A1.X1 - 2 t1 A1.X2 + 
>    2 t1 t2 A1.X2 + t2^2 A2.A2 - 2 t2 A2.X1 + 2 t1 t2 A2.X1 + 2 t2 A2.X2 - 
>    2 t2^2 A2.X2 + X1.X1 - 2 t1 X1.X1 + t1^2 X1.X1 - 2 X1.X2 + 2 t1 X1.X2 + 
>    2 t2 X1.X2 - 2 t1 t2 X1.X2 + X2.X2 - 2 t2 X2.X2 + t2^2 X2.X2

Finally, take derivatives with respect to `t1` and `t2` and use Solve:

```
soln = First @ Solve[{D[expand,t1]==0, D[expand,t2]==0}, {t1, t2}]
```

> {t1 -> -((-(-2 A1.A2 + 2 A1.X2 + 2 A2.X1 - 2 X1.X2) (-2 A2.X1 + 2 A2.X2 + 
>          2 X1.X2 - 2 X2.X2) + (2 A1.X1 - 2 A1.X2 - 2 X1.X1 + 
>          2 X1.X2) (2 A2.A2 - 4 A2.X2 + 2 X2.X2))/(-(-2 A1.A2 + 2 A1.X2 + 
>          2 A2.X1 - 2 X1.X2)^2 + (2 A1.A1 - 4 A1.X1 + 2 X1.X1) (2 A2.A2 - 
>          4 A2.X2 + 2 X2.X2))), 
>    t2 -> -((-A1.A2 A1.X1 + A1.A2 A1.X2 + A1.X1 A1.X2 - (A1.X2)^2 + A1.A1 A2.X1 -
>           A1.X1 A2.X1 - A1.X2 A2.X1 - A1.A1 A2.X2 + 2 A1.X1 A2.X2 + 
>          A1.A2 X1.X1 - A1.X2 X1.X1 - A2.X2 X1.X1 - A1.A1 X1.X2 - A1.A2 X1.X2 + 
>          A1.X1 X1.X2 + 2 A1.X2 X1.X2 + A2.X1 X1.X2 - (X1.X2)^2 + A1.A1 X2.X2 - 
>          2 A1.X1 X2.X2 + X1.X1 X2.X2)/((A1.A2)^2 - 2 A1.A2 A1.X2 + (A1.X2)^2 - 
>          A1.A1 A2.A2 + 2 A1.X1 A2.A2 - 2 A1.A2 A2.X1 + 
>          2 A1.X2 A2.X1 + (A2.X1)^2 + 2 A1.A1 A2.X2 - 4 A1.X1 A2.X2 - 
>          A2.A2 X1.X1 + 2 A2.X2 X1.X1 + 2 A1.A2 X1.X2 - 2 A1.X2 X1.X2 - 
>          2 A2.X1 X1.X2 + (X1.X2)^2 - A1.A1 X2.X2 + 2 A1.X1 X2.X2 - 
>          X1.X1 X2.X2))}

Comment: Thanks a lot! The answer is very intricate, ArgMin[expand] won't work in this case, but it is already very powerful